# flask_script runserver port forwarding not working

Tags: bash, python-3.x, flask-script

I have tried to change the host from `runserver` on bash inside my `virtualenv` which is by default `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` but it doesn't work.

```
(test)srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Documents$ python3 /home/srseven/IdeaProjects/dbooad/dbooad.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 283-681-818
```

why doesn't it work?

Comment: try: `python3 /home/srseven/IdeaProjects/dbooad/dbooad.py runserver 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi same result `test)srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Documents$ python3 /home/srseven/IdeaProjects/dbooad/dbooad.py runserver 0.0.0.0
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 283-681-818
`

Answer (score 0):

I got the error. I was running the app through `app.run` rather than `manager.run`. `manager` is an object of `class Manager` found in `flask-script`.